# Android two sliding drawer in a single view

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I have to insert 2 sliding drawer in my view.
The slidings have to be at the same height( one at the right of the other) and when they open, they have to occupy the entire width of the screen.
If I put them in a Relative layout and I use android:layout_toRightOf, at the open they occupy only an half of the screen's width.
How can I resolve this problem?

thanks

Comment: What is the problem? That they occupy the whole screen, only half or what?

Comment: They occupy the half of the screen and I want that they occupy the whole.